# Force UINavigationBar to layout subviews

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I've got a custom modal presentation that changes adaptively for size classes. The problem is that when a `UINavigationController` is presented the `UINavigationBar` is sized wrong during the animation and then adjusts its height after the animation ends.

Is there a way to force the `UINavigationbar` to relayout before the animation?

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe with
`[self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer removeAllAnimations];` inside `viewWillAppear` method.
That helped me to avoid 20px jump when animating modal dialog which contains UINavigationController.